# Finding duplicate value pairs in SQL

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I have a database that stores first and last names with a user id. The table looks like this:

```
uid value
1   Fred
1   Keller
2   Tim
2   LaChef
3   Adam
3   Adam
```

Having a duplicate `uid` is fine, but I want to find all entries that have the same first and last name though? Like `uid` 3.  Any SQL ideas?

Comment: Why not run a query to check for duplicates, or are you asking something else?

Comment: how do you know it's first or lastname?

Comment: Does case sensitivity matter?

Comment: Please extend the sample data with 4 Adam 4 Sandler and post an expected result form the query.

Comment: Your data does not have first and last names.  Could you fix the data so it matches your problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT uid FROM tablename 
GROUP BY uid, name HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Comment: +1 but for more general i would have choosen COUNT(*) > 1 although it answers the question :o)

Comment: Yes but here we have 2 entries for each id so would prefer count(*)=2

Comment: Michel if you read question than question will say find all ids which have same firstname and lastname. It won't say name with different ids

Comment: As i understand the question it says as i said earlier now we ask to adam that what he wants.

Comment: beware that this may return null duplicates, which may or may not be desired

Answer (score 4):

To return just a single copy of each "duplicate", then:

```
SELECT t.uid
     , t.value
  FROM mytable t
 GROUP
    BY t.uid
     , t.value
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
 ORDER
    BY t.uid
     , t.value
```

To return "all" entries that are duplicates, rather than just one copy, and if you don't need to return any NULL values, then:

```
SELECT a.uid
     , a.value
  FROM mytable a
  JOIN ( SELECT t.uid
              , t.value
           FROM mytable t
          GROUP
             BY t.uid
              , t.value
         HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
       ) d
     ON d.uid = a.uid
    AND d.value = a.value
  ORDER
     BY a.uid
      , a.value
```

---

If you do want to return NULL (where the NULL is a duplicate), then change the comparison operators in the ON clause to the null-safe equality comparison:  `<=>`

```
     ON d.uid <=> a.uid
    AND d.value <=> a.value
```

Comment: <=> produces an error on SQL SERVER 2012, nonetheless if ANSI_NULLS is ON, it won't considere NULL duplicates

Comment: @MauricioQuintana: Yes. The **`<=>`** null-safe comparison operator is a MySQL extension to the SQL standard. That operator isn't supported on SQL Server. (The question was tagged with "mysql", not "sql-server".) OP said he wanted to identify **"all entries that have the same first and last name"**. OP may want to consider a NULL "the same" as a NULL. Multiple rows with `NULL` values will be "grouped" together by a `GROUP BY`, and the individual rows do contribute to the count. The issue addressed by the **`<=>`** isn't about duplicates; it's about returning rows that have `NULL` values.

Comment: @MauricioQuintana: The behavior we get in MySQL with **`a <=> b`** can be emulated in SQL Server by writing  **`(a=b OR (a IS NULL AND b IS NULL))`**.